# mysql check next and previous available period in room availability query

Tags: php, mysql

for a project of mine I would like to add the feature to show the previous and the next available period in a booking reservation system.

I have this query that checks if the house is available:

```
SELECT id
  FROM tbl_reservations
  WHERE (
    `status` LIKE 'confirmed' OR `status` LIKE 'total-payed'
   ) AND (
     '2015-08-12' BETWEEN checkin AND checkout 
     OR checkout BETWEEN '2015-08-12' AND '2015-08-13'
     OR '2015-08-12' BETWEEN checkin AND checkout
     OR checkin BETWEEN '2015-08-12' AND '2015-08-13'
   );
```

If it finds a reservation in that period, the PHP script return false, so it shows a message like

> "Sorry, no availability in that selected period"

I would like to show also something like:

> "The next available period for a stay of XX nights is: "

and then show the checkin and the checkout date.

Same thing for the **previous period**.

I am not mastering sql 100%, so I am here asking for suggestions of any kind to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Obviously **XX nights** refers to the stay length that should be calculated as difference between chckout and checkin.

Comment: `between ` is an inclusive test: `a BETWEEN b AND c` is `(b <= a) && (a <= c)`. so half of your between checks are redundant. the `like 'foo'` is pointless. there's no wildcards, so it's the functional equivalent of `= 'foo'`.

Comment: You're going to have to add more processing upon the return of a 0 result set to check for a day of `XX nights`, this can be done in mysql or php.

Comment: hi @MarcB. Thanks for you reply. The `LIKE 'confirmed` part is not pointless, beacuese there are many states the reservation could be in that moment. Only when it is in those 2 states, the reservation is considered closed. As to the between I could agree, even if, as the system can have 2 reservation in one day (one checking in and the other one checking out) I find it fitting for my needs. Any comment about my request, anyway?

Comment: yes, but you have no wildcards, so a like comparison is pointless. use a normal equality test.

Comment: hi @the_pete. Thank you. Yes, once the query returns 1 (it means there is already a reservation and so NO AVAILABILITY), I could use php to do the math to have the difference or mysql as well with the DATEDIFF() function

Comment: thanks @MarcB. I will do as you suggest.

Comment: @Aptivus my solution solves the question, if it didn't answer your question that's fine.  But if it helped provide you with the solution then accepting it would be a common courtesy.  Thanks and good luck!

Comment: @PhilipDevine You are right. I have marked your solutin as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the two solutions.

Get next available reservation for the expected stay:

```
SELECT id
FROM tbl_reservations
WHERE (
  `status` != 'confirmed' and `status` != 'total-payed'
 )
and checkin = (select min(checkin) from tbl_reservations
               where checkin > '2015-08-12'
                 and checkout - checkin >= '2015-08-12' - '2015-08-13');
```

Get previous reservation for the expected stay.

```
SELECT id
  FROM tbl_reservations
  WHERE (
    `status` != 'confirmed' and `status` != 'total-payed'
   )
  and checkin = (select max(checkin) from tbl_reservations
                 where checkin < '2015-08-12'
                 and checkout - checkin >= '2015-08-12' - '2015-08-13');
```

These can easily be combined into one query, but from the question it looked like you wanted two separate queries.  These are tested and ready to go..

Comment: Thank you very much Philip. I'll give it a try later and post some feedback.

Comment: I tried your "next" query. Well, it works but it returns the next RESERVATION not in the "confirmed" or "total-paied" state  indeed. It should return the empty dates instead.

Comment: i am upvoting your answer because it still has some logical sense and could be used in other occasions. Thank you

Comment: You didn't post you're entire schema i can only give you a solution based on what you tell me. What are the business rules for a date that is not reserved and then i can help you.  Is just a different filter

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this way:

As a visitor is interested mainly in the period he/she has selected, I run the same query for a maximun of 30days before and 30days after the original checkin date.

I break the loop as soon as I get a "false", that means NO RESERVATIONS in theat period.

Maybe it is not the most elegant way or the most performant, but it's working and I am happy :)

Any further suggestion is still accepted. Bettering, always!